# Is ConstraintLayout still preferred over nested Column & Row in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-constraintlayout, android-jetpack-compose

Before Compose, when creating complex UI with XML, it's recommended to avoid nesting views (`RelativeLayout` and `LinearLayout`), and encouraged to use `ConstraintLayout` for achieving complex layouts.

Now Compose has come out, and just by looking at it, `ConstraintLayout` in Compose was so complicated to understand, from my perspective—it's taking more time to figure out how the view should look like with `ConstraintLayout` than with nested `Column` and `Row`.

Honestly, I'd rather go with nested `Column` and `Row` than `ConstraintLayout` in Compose, but I'm not sure about its drawbacks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Short answer: No, nested `Row`s/`Column`s should be fine.

---

Compose is designed to reduce the penalty for nesting layouts, and allow for layouts to be more easily...well, *composed*.  The View system requires non-trivial overhead for each `View` you create, so it was encouraged to avoid nesting them more than necessary and creating extra `View`s.

While it's hard to say that there are *no* situations in which nesting `Row`s and `Column`s will cause a performance problem where `ConstaintLayout` would work well, you shouldn't immediately jump to `ConstraintLayout` when using nested `Row`s/`Column`s would allow you to more easily express your desired layout.

Answer (score 3):

> Compose handles nested layouts efficiently, making them a great way to
> design a complicated UI. This is an improvement from Android Views,
> where you need to avoid nested layouts for performance reasons.

from [Android doc](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/basics#model:%7E:text=Note%3A%20Compose%20handles%20nested%20layouts%20efficiently%2C%20making%20them%20a%20great%20way%20to%20design%20a%20complicated%20UI.%20This%20is%20an%20improvement%20from%20Android%20Views%2C%20where%20you%20need%20to%20avoid%20nested%20layouts%20for%20performance%20reasons.)